Spherical aberration of lens
Why is spherical aberration absent in an image formed by a plano-convex lens on its principal axis? Will it be present in other types of lenses?

Both lenses shown have spherical aberration. For many uses, the spherical aberration of a plano convex lens is small enough not to matter. For other uses, it isn't good enough.
An ideal lens would focus all the incoming rays shown to a single point. For a singlet lens, that would take an aspherical shape. If you are restricted to spherical surfaces (much easier to manufacture), rays away from the axis come to a focus the wrong distance from the lens. This error in distance is called spherical aberration.
You can reduce it by choosing different radii and thickness. Or by making a compound lens out of multiple elements, where a positive spherical aberration of one element is cancelled by a negative spherical aberration of another.
There are several aberrations. Spherical aberration is usually the most important. Sometimes correcting it is enough for a given use. For cameras, all the aberrations need to be corrected. For more information about aberrations, see Optical Aberrations
For information about several categories of lenses for different imaging purposes, see Objectives
For information on approximations in lenses, see my answer to Is there a more accurate form of the mirror equation $1/f=1/u+1/v$
? The question is about mirrors, but I talk about lenses too.


From the picture, you can see that the biconvex lens has a second bent surface through which light is travelling through. Julie Benson and Craig Olson (and others in the optical design area) call this "lens bending" (see here: https://www.spiedigitallibrary.org/ebooks/FG/Field-Guide-to-Lens-Design/Lens-Bending/Lens-Bending/10.1117/3.934997.ch54#_=_). This parameter is a measure of the focal length in proportion to the angle of the surfaces through which light travels.
Spherical aberration is proportional to the height of the beam relative to the beam: Therefore, the more non-planar surfaces you have, the higher the proportion of the beam that will travel a longer distance than the on-axis ray and thus larger amount of spherical aberrations.
